# call to undefined method ***::all()... Eloquent/Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

So I have a file Classes.php (and I do have a table 'classes' in my database)

```
<?php

namespace KQHT;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Classes extends Model

{
    protected $table = "classes";
}
```

and I write this in file route.php

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
        $myClass = Classes::all();
        return $myClass;
    });
```

but when I run, it returns this error

```
FatalErrorException in routes.php line 46:
Call to undefined method Classes::all()
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: it's `App\Classes::all()`. if you changed the namespace it must be `KQHT\Classes`

Comment: Sure you are calling the correct class/namespace? Maybe `\KQHT\Classes::all()`?

Comment: It works fine now. Thanks for your kind helps